# Change the scene mode in Cesium every interval

Tags: cesium

I have a task which 
I want to change the scene mode in Cesium every 1 mins.
For example, let say be default the scene mode is 3D. after 1 mins, it will change to 2D mode and then anohter. I used refresh feature to change the scene mode. Here is my code below.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <!-- Use correct character set. -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <!-- Tell IE to use the latest, best version. -->
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <!-- Make the application on mobile take up the full browser screen and disable user scaling. -->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
      <title>Hello World!</title>
      <script src="../Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
      <style>
          @import url(../Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css);
          html, body, #cesiumContainer {
              width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
          }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
    var scene = viewer.scene;
    scene.mode= Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE3D;
    var scenename = "3D";
    console.log("Scene Mode 3D");

     //updateFromServer();
    var intervalID = window.setInterval(updateFromServer, 6000);

    function updateFromServer() {
        if (scenename = "3D")
        {
            var scene = viewer.scene;
            scene.mode= Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE2D;
            //document.cookie = "SceneMode=2D;";
            scenename = "2D";
            console.log("Scene Mode 2D");
        }
        else
        {
            var scene = viewer.scene;
            scene.mode= Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE3D;
            scenename = "3D";
            console.log("Scene Mode 3D");
        }
    }

      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It does not work except my console.log.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a single '=' sign in the condition which assigns scenename to"3D".
Instead, in your if statement use '===' to compare the value of scenemane . Use

```
 if (scenename === "3D"){ 
//the rest of the code
}
```

p.s.
you also don't need to re-declare scene `var scene = viewer.scene;` inside the updateFromServer() function.